Math problem in Lauren Child's "Ruby Redfort: Look into my eyes"
In the children's book "Ruby Redfort: Look Into My Eyes", the main character is asked to simplify the following expression:
$$9! \prod_{p \ prime}\Big[\Big(1-\frac{1}{p}\Big)^4\Big(1+\frac{4}{p}+\frac{1}{p^2}\Big)\Big]^{-1} \lim_{T \to \infty} \frac{1}{T \log^9 T} \int_1^{T}\Bigg\lvert \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^{-(1/2 + i t)}\Bigg\rvert^{6}dt$$
The book lists the answer at the back of the book as 42, and I was wondering if this was correct, or just some mumbo jumbo with an answer attached. There are some things we can recognize here:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^{-(1/2 + i t)} = \zeta(\frac{1}{2} + it)$$
so the integral amounts to an integral over the critical strip of the absolute value of the zeta function to the sixth power (This is the main thing that makes me think the question is nonsense). The product over primes is also reminiscent of the Euler product, although I don't see how to put the operand into the form $(1-p^{-s})^{-1}$. Furthermore, I don't understand the denominator $\frac{1}{T \log^9 T}$: this seems like nonsense.
Is there anything here? I'd appreciate any help in simplifying this expression, or in explaining why it's impossible!

cultural thing... Radio series The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy  gives the answer to the Question of Life, the Universe, and Everything as $42$  Pretty funny the way it was done  https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/for-math-fans-a-hitchhikers-guide-to-the-number-42/

@WillJagy Your reference is not relevant in this case. The equation in the question is indeed conjectured to be equal to $42$. This is a special case of the Keating-Snaith conjecture for the $2k$-th moment of the Riemann zeta function. See eqn. (4) of this paper: https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/~mancs/papers/RMTzeta.pdf

I should add, however, that the statement is wrong in the sense that the sum $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} n^{-(1/2 + it)}$ does not converge and is not the correct representation of $\zeta(1/2 + it)$. One can get around this using tools such as the approximate functional equation.

@PeterHumphries  suggest you post an answer. One ingredient: the author got help from Marcus du Sautoy  for, at least, the secret codes in the books.

Thanks so much Peter!!
